# How to structure AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm planning on developing single page app with AngularJS. I'm not sure however how to structure it best.

I'm thinking to have one controller wrapping the content. This controller will keep details of the user e.g. if user is logged in, username etc. It will wrap `ng-view` loaded dynamically and directives within it.

What I'm not sure about is how to deal with asynchronous calls. For example if I load one of the views and there will be 3 directives within it, structure might be similar to this:

```
- wrapping controller
-- ng-view (here views are loaded dynamically). When view loaded it will contains e.g.:
--- some directive that needs information about user
--- another directive that needs information about user
--- yet another directive that needs information about user
```

Each of these directives will need information if the user is logged in or not and so each of these directives will have to make a `$http` call to backend to find out if user is logged in or not. This means that there will be 3 calls to backend but it would make sense to have only one.

If however I move this functionality to wrapping controller it will request login information from backend and store as should. However as this $http request to server is asynchronous the directive that loads initially inside the page will not be aware if the user is logged in or not and will not be able to display itself properly. I might end up with something like this:

1. page loads
2. wrapping controller executes and makes asynchronous call to backend to find out if user is logged in or not
3. particular view is loaded. It grabs information from wrapping controller and sees that user is not logged in at this point (wrapping controller did not receive information from backend just yet). Directive redirects to homepage.
4. wrapping controller finally receives information from server saying user is logged in but directive already redirected user to homepage.

I hope my explanation makes sense. I'm sure there is common pattern to use in situations like that. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you check a proven fullstack solution like [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/). Their [open-source code](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) is available on github.

When the application header loads in meanjs, it goes like this:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 
    function($scope, Authentication) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    }
]);
```

The controller in the nav menu calls the Authentication service, and adds it to the scope.

> there will be 3 calls to backend but it would make sense to have only one

Indeed you can make one call to a service from the page controller. Then any directives which need the authentication information could inherit from the page controller.

Any directive can do likewise, include the Authentication service to get the Authentication info.

Some directives will show/hide depending on whether the user is authenticated or not, like so:

```
<ul data-ng-hide="authentication.user">
```

If you use ui-router, you can use resolve in your routing to catch the authentication information before displaying your view.

> particular view is loaded. It grabs information from wrapping controller and sees that user is not logged in at this point (wrapping controller did not receive information from backend just yet). Directive redirects to homepage.

Or you can wait until your promise resolves, and return with the information about whether the user is authenticated or not. In the meantime, you can display a logo, a spinner, a blank page...

Comment: Accepted the answer as I went with promise implementation that seems to work